# antd+react.js show table rows when clicking on table header

Tags: reactjs, antd, panel

i have a list of rows
[image]

and i want to show the content of a row when clicking on it
[image]
i did it using Panel and Collapse of antd but i am not really satisfied
and i am looking for a solution using **Table: expand table rows when clicking on the header** ( i found "expandable" an attribute of antd Table but its related to expandable rows and its not really what i want)

Comment: why don't you use collapse? https://ant.design/components/collapse/

Comment: actually i am using collapse and every panel contains a table of elements, but i have problems when i want to align table columns with the informations in the blue rectangle

Comment: You can add `onClick` function on Table Header using `onHeaderRow` prop. When click on table header, save all rows keys (get it from your dataSource) in a state. Pass that keys array to `expandedRowKeys` in expandable prop.